# Where can our small non-profit find assistance with CiviCRM?

Tags: developer

Looking for an individual in Michigan, USA, to assist with understanding a civicrm database that was created for our non-profit.  Many bugs and errors in the system, and training on system needed for staff.
Recommendations needed ASAP.
Thanks 
M Janes

Answer (score 4):

Best place to look for a CiviCRM Partner/Contributor is here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors - there are many Partners/Contributors in the US - even if you can't locate one in Michigan - with today's tools like GoToMeeting so much can be done online;

Answer (score 0):

I agree with KarinG. Another option that could potentially produce some local results is Craigslist.